# UIDocument not working

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentinteraction

I'm trying to open document file by following way but nothing happens.
I tried other ways too but it didn't work for me. What is the correct way open Document file (doc,docx,pdf,ppt, etc.). I read somewhere by `UIWebView()` also this can be done so what is the better way?

```
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentMessage.fileUrl)

let doc = DocumentPreview(fileURL)
doc.startPreview()
```

DocumentPreview.swift

```
class DocumentPreview : NSObject, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    var url : URL?
    var document : UIDocumentInteractionController?
    var previewVC : UINavigationController?

    init(_ url: URL) {
        super.init()
        self.url = url
        document = UIDocumentInteractionController(url:url)
        document?.delegate = self
    }

    func startPreview(){
        document?.presentPreview(animated:true)
    }

    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return previewVC!
    }

    func documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
        print("end Preview")
        previewVC!.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help me when alternate way if available.

Comment: I was doing this completely wrong. First I was passing remote URL but now I'm downloading file first saving it into DOC Directory and then passing that url to this and it works. But one problem, wouldn't this increase app size ? how to handle that ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at documentMessage.  If the .fileUrl property is a URL, then this code is wrong:

```
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentMessage.fileUrl)
```

The simplest fix would be this:

```
let fileURL = documentMessage.fileUrl
```

Comment: Thanks it should be String. but now app crashes on         document = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url) in DocumentPreview.swift

Comment: Great. Accept this answer and describe your next problem. It wouldn't hurt to click on the up arrow for this answer as well.  This site requires handling one problem at a time. It looks like you will have a few. If you expect too much, people will avoid your questions. but it's easy. Just describe your new problem as well as you can, any steps you might have taken to try to solve it...